# Why did I get IO exception when i use SparkSql to access hive table in zeppelin?

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

There are some tables in Hive Database,i want to access one of it with SparkSql in zeppelin ,but i got the error message,like this:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in 
stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 
(TID 3, cloud01, executor 1): java.io.IOException: Connection from 
/x.x.x.x:42826 closed
```

cluster version:

```
spark:2.2.0
hive:2.1.1
zeppelin:0.8.0
centos7
```

This is my code:

```
%spark
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
val hc = new HiveContext(sc)
var data = hc.sql("select * from cqdrg.drg_table_xy3j limit 10")
```

it can print schema:

```
data.printSchema()
root
 |-- batch: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cid: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- bbq_: string (nullable = true)
 |-- userid_: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ylfkfs: string (nullable = true)
 |-- jkkh: string (nullable = true)
 |-- bah: string (nullable = true)
 |-- xm: string (nullable = true)
 |-- xb: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sfzh: string (nullable = true)
 |-- csrq: string (nullable = true)
```

but when i want to look data

```
data.show()
```

i got error as below:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, cloud03, executor 2): java.io.IOException: Connection from /x.x.x.x:35332 closed
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.channelInactive(TransportResponseHandler.java:146)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelInactive(TransportChannelHandler.java:108)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:227)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:220)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelInactive(IdleStateHandler.java:278)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:227)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:220)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:227)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:220)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelInactive(TransportFrameDecoder.java:182)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:227)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:220)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1289)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:227)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:893)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:691)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:446)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

this is Interpreter config:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKym6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

well,i change the version of zeppelin from 0.8.0 to 0.7.3
there is no problem.